# Why do most U.S. companies pay their dividends quarterly, as opposed to annually?

Tags: stocks, dividends

U.S. companies usually pay quarterly dividends. Why do they pay them quarterly, and not once per year after the end of their fiscal year (as is usual, for example, for Swiss and German companies)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because some investors like a regular income stream in fact a substantial number of UK Investment Trusts pay quarterly dividends for this reason.

The idea being if you have a selection of quarterly paying investments you can get a monthly income.

I suspect that German companies are more tightly held and do not treat outside smaller investors with the respect that they should - ask a German company about employee share options and you will see what I mean.